# How to add lvm so its available to use?

Tags: disk-space, gparted, lvm

I'v got this 276GB disk that I can't figure out how to add to my volume group so that it is usable.

Is there any way to make it usable?

[image: screengrab]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the name of your volume group - `vgdisplay` will do that for you as will a quick look into `/dev/mapper`.

Assuming your VG is called "vgname" you now need to do `vgextend vgname /dev/sda2`, then you can create the LVs.

Comment: ok so sda2 is now in the same volume group "fedora", I tried creating the logical volume, but it still wont show up as usable space. Does it need to be formatted to a different file system type?

Comment: What does `pvdisplay -m` show?

Comment: --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda6
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               21.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5374
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          5374
  PV UUID               mq2f21-q7je-bd3C-lgYY-MeB5-cepJ-UrOs82
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 1955:
    Logical volume /dev/fedora/swap
    Logical extents 0 to 1955
  Physical extent 1956 to 5373:
    Logical volume /dev/fedora/root
    Logical extents 0 to 3417

Comment: { --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               fedora
  PV Size               276.57 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              70800
  Free PE               70780
  Allocated PE          20
  PV UUID               hvTGQ3-lQzE-MbJI-YfUD-N7WX-Idbs-65EBpu
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 19:
    Logical volume /dev/fedora/logical_vol1
    Logical extents 0 to 19
  Physical extent 20 to 70799:
    FREE}

Comment: So sda2 has 70800 free PEs - `lvcreate -n YOURNAME -l 100%FREE fedora` should do the trick.